# How to detect youtube player finish playing

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Hi I am trying to track/detect the youtube player finish video so i can redirect page into a new url. i found code somewhere but problem is that its not working in IE, have a look into my code

```
http://jsfiddle.net/yhb9yf21/
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>
    
    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '7oGgzGPK1SY',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('done');
        }
    }
    
</script>
```

its not working with IE???

Comment: work on IE11 for me...

Comment: I do not have IE 11, i have IE 10 and in IE 10 its not working